# Git pre-commit hooks only for a specific subfolder?

Tags: git, hook, pre-commit

I currently have a single repo with two projects, each in their own subfolder: one in C# and one in Javascript. I want to have a pre-commit hook that will run jshint but only if any of the staged files are in the Javascript folder If the staged files are only from the C# folder, then the pre-commit hook won't run.

Is it that possible at all? Or is my only solution to split the two projects into their own repos?

Comment: How the repository is divided ? a branch for each projects ?

Comment: Same problem here. We have an independent project per directory all in the same git repo and if I'm commiting a directory, I want to run only that directory's tests

Comment: I wrote a little tool https://pypi.org/project/hooks4git/ to help to handle git hooks. Although it is not directly supported, you can call a custom script on its configuration file which solves your question. But this tool can easily be upgraded to support that. I liked the idea and created a issue there: https://github.com/lovato/hooks4git/issues/23

Answer (score 35):

If you use [pre-commit](https://pre-commit.com/), specify `files` to include (or `exclude` to exclude) specific directories, e.g. run hooks only in `my_dir`:

```
files: ^my_dir/
repos:
-   repo: https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit-hooks
    hooks:
        ...
```

or run everywhere but inside `my_dir`:

```
exclude: ^my_dir/
repos:
-   repo: https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit-hooks
    hooks:
        ...
```

If you have a long list of exclusions, use verbose regex:

```
exclude: >
  (?x)^(
      path/to/file1.py|
      path/to/file2.py|
      path/to/file3.py
  )$
```

you can also apply these to specific hooks only, just do:

```
-   id: my-hook
    exclude: ^my_dir/
```

Comment: Maybe add just a small notice that the multiline is for files only.  The `$` at the end might throw some people off.  Debugged this for some time before I notice it.

Comment: How do I choose two folders?

Comment: What are you supposed to do with this YAML code? Precommit hooks are just sh/cmd  scripts, so where are you supposed to use this?

Comment: This YAML is used in https://pre-commit.com/

Comment: The pre-commit is a bash script to why show an example with yaml.

Answer (score 4):

[Here](https://superuser.com/questions/552617/execute-git-pre-commit-hook-only-if-files-in-certain-directory-modified) are good native solutions.

I use something like this

```sh
if git diff --cached --quiet -- "frontend/"
then
  echo "Unchanged"
  exit 0
else
  echo "Changed"
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using pre-commit newer than v1.1.0, then you can add a `exclude` field to your `.pre-commit-config.yaml` which is located in the root folder of your repo.

Just like below:

```
exclude: '^(?!javascript/)'
```

Check the document [here](https://pre-commit.com/#pre-commit-configyaml---top-level)

Comment: can this be made to *include* a specific folder only though?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `git log` to find out if the latest commit in a subdir matches the latest commit at your repository root:

```
#!/bin/env bash

function get_commit {
    git log --oneline -- $1 | head -n 1 | cut -d " " -f1
}

ROOT_COMMIT=$(get_commit)
SUBDIR_COMMIT=$(get_commit my/subdir/path)

if [ "$SUBDIR_COMMIT" == "$ROOT_COMMIT" ]; then
    # do pre-commit hook stuff here
fi
```

Answer (score -1):

Git hooks are scripts that Git runs before or after it does specific things.

If you write a script and save it as `<repository_name>/.git/hooks/pre-commit` then git will run it before committing. So write a simple script for the operating system you are using that runs jshint against that subfolder and save it to that path.

Git doesn't run your pre-commit hook with any arguments. You can use git commands to figure out the state of your repository (the changes added as part of the commit are still just staged and accessible through --cached). If you make any changes and want them to become part of the commit, you'll need to add them before the script exits.

You are working with C# so you should be aware that git hooks on windows are a bit quirky: [Executing Git hooks on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18277429/executing-git-hooks-on-windows)