Pre-push not execute before push
Could you please help me? I have a problem with pre-push hook. When I push code to remote repository the push succeeds without any check that I mentions in pre-push script. But when I run ktlintCheck via gradle it founds mistakes right away.
Here is the setting of pre-push. As you can see it's in hook folder as it supposed to be.


I think you should remove the [mobile-development] tag. Your question has nothing to do with it, does it?

Minor nit: you don't need if and exit at the end of the script. gradle ktlintCheck returns the status from the shell script if it is the last command.

That is to say: The default behavior of a shell script on reaching the end of the code is exit $?, just as the default behavior of a function is return $?.

Anyhow -- did you set file permissions? Is your hook actually executable? (As a separate point, any echo meant to generate logs for human users to read should have a >&2 redirecting its output to stderr)

When I run chmod +x .git/hooks/pre-push I get CommandNotFoundException
"chmod : The name “chmod” is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program. Check that the name is spelled correctly and that the path is present and correct, then try again."

Oh, you're on Windows. There's a lot that's different there, and it really needs to be part of the question -- for example, the #!/bin/bash shebang is completely meaningless, unless you're using a copy of git compiled with a UNIX compatibility library such as msys or cygwin. (It looks like "Git for Windows" does support some level of POSIX shell compatibility, per the answers to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18277429/executing-git-hooks-on-windows, but is that even the git build/distribution you're using?)
